# Why doesnot ApolloQueryWatcher trigger after a mutation change data?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, apollo-android

After following Support Caching in Apollo Android 
here: [Support For Cached Responses for Android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#support-for-cached-responses)

And already tried to query offline and it works fine and data is coming from the cache

- First scenario after opening the app is loading the list of Data using Query from "MyApolloClient" object which is a custom class inherit from "ApolloClient"
- After getting the data using ".watcher().enqueueAndWatch()" method to callback response from Apollo with new data and update the recyclerView
- I select item to update or "Mutate" a record from the query data list to change it in cache and database of course.

> I can click on any item and then it show a dialog to edit name of that
>   record item

After sending the updated name using `Mutation` normally, the cache changed and the database online changed too.

**The problem here:** the UI doesn't changed at all because `.watcher()` method which returns instance of `ApolloQueryWatcher` who has a method called `enqueueAndWatch` **doesn't trigger** as a listener to any changes to update UI and the list with the new changed value of that record

Here are some snippets from my Code, 
I am using Kotlin and Java.

- The Method to get data of users from database using Query

  ```
  fun getAllUsers() {
  progress.visibility = VISIBLE
  MyApolloClient.getApolloClient(this).query(GetUsersWithPagesQuery.builder().build())
      .watcher().enqueueAndWatch(object : MyApolloClient.MyCallBack<GetUsersWithPagesQuery.Data>(this) {
          override fun onResponseUI(response: Response<GetUsersWithPagesQuery.Data>) {
              progress.visibility = GONE
              if (response.data() != null) {
                  reachBottom = false
                  users.clear()
                  for (i in response.data()!!.users()) {
                      val u = GetUsersWithPagesQuery.Data1("", i.id(), i.name(), i.email())
                      users.add(u)
                  }
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

              }
          }

          override fun onFailureUI(response: ApolloException) {

          }
      })
  ```

  }
- Custom Callback to use response in UI

  ```
  public static abstract class MyCallBack<T> extends ApolloCall.Callback<T> {

  Activity activity;

  public MyCallBack(Activity activity) {
      this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(@NotNull com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<T> response) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(() -> onResponseUI(response));

  }

  public abstract void onResponseUI(@NotNull com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<T> response);

  public abstract void onFailureUI(@NotNull ApolloException response);

  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(() -> onFailureUI(e));
  }
  ```

  }
- getting object of Apollo Client with Caching support

  ```
  public static ApolloClient getApolloClient(Context context) {

  HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
  httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
  OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
  builder.addNetworkInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
  builder.addNetworkInterceptor(chain -> {
      Request original = chain.request();
      Request.Builder builder1 = original.newBuilder().method(original.method(), original.body());
      builder1.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + PrefManager.getInstance(context).getAPIToken());
      return chain.proceed(builder1.build());
  });
  OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
  //Directory where cached responses will be stored
  File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "apolloCache");

  //Size in bytes of the cache
  long size = 1024 * 1024;

  //Create the http response cache store
  DiskLruHttpCacheStore cacheStore = new DiskLruHttpCacheStore(file, size);

  ApolloSqlHelper apolloSqlHelper = ApolloSqlHelper.create(context, "zari");

  //Create NormalizedCacheFactory
  NormalizedCacheFactory cacheFactory = new SqlNormalizedCacheFactory(apolloSqlHelper);

  //Create the cache key resolver, this example works well when all types have globally unique ids.
  CacheKeyResolver resolver = new CacheKeyResolver() {
      @NotNull
      @Override
      public CacheKey fromFieldRecordSet(@NotNull ResponseField field, @NotNull Map<String, Object> recordSet) {
          return formatCacheKey((String) recordSet.get("id"));
      }

      @NotNull
      @Override
      public CacheKey fromFieldArguments(@NotNull ResponseField field, @NotNull Operation.Variables variables) {
          return formatCacheKey((String) field.resolveArgument("id", variables));
      }

      private CacheKey formatCacheKey(String id) {
          if (id == null || id.isEmpty()) {
              return CacheKey.NO_KEY;
          } else {
              return CacheKey.from(id);
          }
      }
  };

  apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
          .serverUrl(url)
          //.httpCache(new ApolloHttpCache(cacheStore))
          .normalizedCache(cacheFactory, resolver)
          .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
          .build();
  return apolloClient;
  ```

  }
- alert dialog with edit text to update item from list in Recycler Adapter

  ```
  builder.setPositiveButton("Change", (dialog, which) -> {
      if (!n.isEmpty())
          MyApolloClient.getApolloClient(activity).mutate(UpdateUserMutation.builder().id(user
                  .id()).name(n).build()).enqueue(new MyApolloClient.MyCallBack<UpdateUserMutation.Data>(activity) {
              @Override
              public void onResponseUI(@NotNull Response<UpdateUserMutation.Data> response) {
                  if (response.errors() != null && response.errors().size() > 0) {
                      StaticMembers.toastMessageShort(activity, response.errors().get(0).message());
                  } else {
                      StaticMembers.toastMessageShort(activity, response.data().updateUser().name() + " updated");
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailureUI(@NotNull ApolloException response) {

              }
          });

  });
  ```

So, Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Apollo-android has no way to know what node your mutation is going to modify. If your API allows it, you could query the new user as return data from the mutation to force an update of the cache.

Alternatively, you could modify the cache by hand if the request succeeds but that seems more involved.